# How can I force Go's standard xml parser to read DTD entities

Tags: xml, go, dtd

I'm using go's `encoding/xml` package to parse an XML file. When parsing a file, here's the error I get :

```
XML syntax error on line 16: invalid character entity &uuml;
```

But the xml file references a dtd :

```
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">
```

And that dtd itself contains the definition of that entity :

```
    <!ENTITY uuml    "&#252;" ><!-- small u, dieresis or umlaut mark -->
```

Is there a way to force Go's xml parser to parse DTDs, did I miss something somewhere or am I doomed to use a third-party xml parser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the answer you would like to hear...

You could use the `Entity`-field of `http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder`. Unfortunately I do not know of an automatic way to generate such entity maps from a dtd. But this should be straightforward to extract from the dtd. If the dtd doesn't change this might be a nice task for `go generate`.

If the list if entities is fixed (and small enough) I would hardcode the entity map.

Comment: Hah, not the answer I was expecting, that's sure. I had seen this solution but was expecting to be able to avoid it. I'll try to `go generate it`, good point, thanks a lot. I'll try to contribute a parser that takes entities into consideration if I find the time.